# jQuery seed each() with an array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

The script below is throwing an error (customfields is not defined). Do I need to pass the element IDs differently?

I'm trying to seed the array with the form fields that I'm looking to calculate. It should iterate through each of the form fields in the array and increment the sum variable with the value of the form element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('style','width:60px');
    jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('disabled','disabled');

    var customfields = [
    '#customfield_11070',
    '#customfield_11071',
    '#customfield_20071',
    '#customfield_20072',   
    '#customfield_20073',
    '#customfield_20074'
    ];

    jQuery(customfields).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('style','width:60px');

            jQuery(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });


        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;

        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        jQuery(customfields).each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.id !== "customfield_21070") {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        jQuery("#customfield_21070").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.each()` method is meant to iterate over a jQuery object. You should use a simple `for` loop to iterate your array – it's a lot faster than using the jQuery `.each()` method, anyway.

```
for(var i=0, len=customfields.length; i<len; i++) {
    console.log(customfields[i]);
}
```

Proof about performance claims: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: I think your answer makes sense. Console.log is working. Now i just need to get the calculate function to work > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091742/jquery-passing-array-values-into-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array to jQuery is not going to use the entries in the array as selectors. You have to pass the selector as a string. When you call `this.value` the `this` is actually a string and not an element. Try

```
jQuery(customfields.join(','))
```

Comment: However, it will treat it as an array of strings, he is then selecting them inside the each properly.

Comment: @KevinB in the first .each which I believe is a coincidence, but not in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the [**jQuery.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(customfields, function (index, value) {
    $(value).attr('style', 'width:60px');  // OR $(value).width(60);
    $(value).keyup(function () {
        calculateSum();
    });
});
```