# passing array values into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

In the script below, the console.log is returning the correct values, and both alerts fire. However, the value is coming up undefined.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('style','width:60px');
    jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('disabled','disabled');

    var customfields = [
    '#customfield_11070',
    '#customfield_11071',
    '#customfield_20071',
    '#customfield_20072',   
    '#customfield_20073',
    '#customfield_20074',
    ];

    for(var i=0, len=customfields.length; i<len; i++) {
        console.log(customfields[i]);
        jQuery(customfields[i]).keyup(function(){
            alert('calculate');//FIRES
            calculateSum();
        });
    }


    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;

        alert('value: ' + this.value);//UNDEFINED

        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.id !== "customfield_21070") {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

        jQuery("#customfield_21070").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

});
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to the keyup'd element in `calculateSum`.

Comment: `this` in the current context it's in in your `calculateSum` function isn't calling anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> Calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided
>   individually.

Its first parameter is `thisArg`:

> The value of `this` provided for the call to fun. Note that `this` may not
>   be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in
>   non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the
>   global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

So, pass `this` from your handler function to `calculateSum` like so:

```
jQuery(customfields[i]).keyup(function(){
    calculateSum.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`@canon` is absolutely correct, following as he said will resolve your Issue.

You can possibly write :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('style', 'width:60px');
            jQuery("#customfield_21070").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            var customfields = [
            '#customfield_11070',
            '#customfield_11071',
            '#customfield_20071',
            '#customfield_20072',
            '#customfield_20073',
            '#customfield_20074',
            ];

            for (var i = 0, len = customfields.length; i < len; i++) {
                jQuery(customfields[i]).keyup(function () {
                    calculateSum(this);//Edited
                });
            }


            function calculateSum(param) {//Edited

                var sum = 0;

                alert('value: ' + param.value);//UNDEFINED

                if (!isNaN(param.value) && param.value.length != 0 && param.id !== "customfield_21070") {//Edited
                    sum += parseFloat(param.value);
                }

                jQuery("#customfield_21070").val(sum.toFixed(2));
            }

        });
```

This reflects proper value in your `alert`. `**Tested**`